# Tombstone never deleted in __consumer_offsets topic. Why?

Tags: apache-kafka

I notices that in **__consumer_offsets** topic there are many tombstone even if I have set **log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 0**

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --consumer.config /tmp/consumer.config --formatter "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter" --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic __consumer_offsets --from-beginning
...
[b316,test,25]::[OffsetMetadata[35,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1623427715903,ExpirationTime 1623427775903]
[b316,test,61]::[OffsetMetadata[35,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1623427715903,ExpirationTime 1623427775903]
[b316,test,41]::[OffsetMetadata[34,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1623427715903,ExpirationTime 1623427775903]
[b316,test,5]::[OffsetMetadata[34,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1623427715903,ExpirationTime 1623427775903]
...
[b316,test,50]::NULL
[b316,test,70]::NULL
[b316,test,54]::NULL
[b316,test,31]::NULL
...
```

How is this possible? Why it doesn't delete the tumbstones?

Comment: What is the timestamp of Null value messages?

Comment: @nipuna there isn't the timestamp of that messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tomstone a message after compacted, `current time - compacted time` should be grater than [`delete.retention.ms`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_delete.retention.ms). It is defaulted by broker config [`log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms). So in your case it is zero. But this is applied for compacted logs.

But to compact kafka messages in logs, `not compacted / compacted + not compacted` ratio it is called `dirty ratio` should be greater than config `min.cleanable.dirty.ratio`, `defaul = is 0.5`. Active segment is not considered for this calculations.

So in your scenario, they are not still compacted. That is why they are remaining in the topic.

For more info about compaction and tombstone [refer this](https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/an-investigation-into-kafka-log-compaction-5e520f4291f0)

Comment: So you mean that the tombstones still stay in the segment because that segment is not compacted?

Comment: Yes exactly. because that dirty ratio is still lower than threshold